# AsyncTask and SQLite Database

Tags: android

What's the best way to access the database through an async task?

I don't think I should pass in a reference to the DbAdapter that the activity is using (could be closed as the activity may be garbage-collected).

Also, the db needs a context to be opened and closed, but I don't have that with the async task.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` is an abstract class, so you have to extend it.

Create a class which extends `AsyncTask`, then in the constructor of this class you can add every things you want like the `Context`.